# PL/SQL split varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get this from a table `John Doe`.

What is the best way to split this to have into two variable this :

```
lastName = 'Doe';
firstName = 'John';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should work :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(NameColumn, 1, INSTR(NameColumn,' ',1)) AS firstName,
SUBSTR(NameColumn, INSTR(NameColumn,' ',1)+1) FROM tablName
```

Comment: I might go wrong in indexing and position calculation, so do add suggestive comments and modification (I've kept it open for Wiki community)

Comment: Using regular expressions:   with tbl as (
select 'John Doe' str from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str, '([^ ]*)( |$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) first_name,
       regexp_substr(str, '([^ ]*)( |$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) last_name
from tbl;

Comment: thanks :), I am lil bit climsy when it comes to regular expressions. But i'll do a self-study on regex again. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Just another way to approach it.  Good to know as nested INSTR/SUBSTR can get ugly.  I guess it's up to the developer to decide if it's uglier than the regular expression.  heh